Running X11 session from SDDM on Wayland
I'd like to open a new X11 user session from SDDM on Wayland.
Default SDDM behavior is to run on X11. Thus, it starts X11 server first, then it can successfully start a session first for itself, and then it creates new session for the user. Also it can open a Wayland session for the user just fine.
If SDDM is running on Wayland though, it's different. Since it doesn't start X11 server first, it then simply tries to open an X11 session for the user and fails since there's no X11 server.
Is there anything that can be done? Like, starting X11 server if it's not up yet right before trying to create an X11 session?
Without such feature, it seems that SDDM on Wayland can only open Wayland sessions.
Details: Arch Linux, SDDM 0.21.0-4, Wayland 1.22.0-1, Xorg 21.1.13-1, Plasma 6.0.5-1
